# Unique pairs in R, ignoring order

Tags: r

Say I have a dataframe like this:

```
dat<-data.frame(c("a", "b", "c"), c("b", "a", "d"), stringsAsFactors=F)
colnames(dat)<-c("V1", "V2")
dat
#    V1  V2
# 1   a   b
# 2   b   a
# 3   c   d
```

What I want to do is, with each row being a pair, generate all unique pairs, ignoring order. So my output would be something like

```
unique_pairs(dat$V1, dat$V2)

# Output
#   V1  V2
# 1  a   b
# 2  c   d
```

What would be the most efficient way of doing this?

Comment: What would be the output for `data.frame(c('b', 'a', 'c'), c('a', 'd', 'c'))`?

Comment: The output would be identical to the input, since there are no repeating matching pairs

Comment: Ah, now I get it. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One option (as answered by @bgoldst) is to sort each row individually with `apply`. However, we'll get better performance for large data frames operating on the columns using a single call to `pmin` and `pmax` instead of on the rows using many calls to `sort`:

```
# Make a larger data frame by sampling
set.seed(144)
dat.large <- dat[sample(nrow(dat), 10000, replace=T),]

# Row-wise and column-wise computations
rowwise <- function(dat) unique(t(apply(dat, 1, sort)))
colwise <- function(dat) unique(cbind(pmin(dat[,1], dat[,2]), pmax(dat[,1], dat[,2])))
all.equal(unname(rowwise(dat.large)), unname(colwise(dat.large)))
# [1] TRUE

# Compare performance
library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(rowwise(dat.large), colwise(dat.large))
# Unit: milliseconds
#                expr       min        lq      mean    median        uq      max neval
#  rowwise(dat.large) 465.45604 523.49464 564.91541 559.14461 595.58961 805.7982   100
#  colwise(dat.large)  33.69199  42.91692  50.87839  47.70415  53.06705 122.4459   100
```

As you can see, for a 10000-row input the columnwise operation is about 10 times faster, showing the power of vectorization when computing in R. Obviously the speedup from 500 ms to 50 ms is probably not a big deal, but if you're dealing with large datasets the vectorized approach is likely preferable.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `apply()` to sort each row, coerce back to `data.frame` (because `apply()` will return a matrix), then run it through `unique()`:

```
dat <- data.frame(c('a','b','c'), c('b','a','d'), stringsAsFactors=F );
colnames(dat) <- c('V1','V2');
x <- unique(as.data.frame(t(apply(dat, 1, sort ))));
rownames(x) <- 1:nrow(x);
x;
```

Output:

```
  V1 V2
1  a  b
2  c  d
```

Comment: Would it provide the right answer for the Konrad's example, i.e. `data.frame(c('b', 'a', 'c'), c('a', 'd', 'c'))`?

Comment: @MaratTalipov Yes, I just checked and it produces the correct answer