# R, Select first dataframe row for each unique pair, ignoring order

Tags: r

There are lots of question the flirt around this issue, but I haven't been able to find answer to my particular concern. I have a dataframe that has this general format.

```
dat <- data.frame(V1 = c(1,1,2,1,2,4,5), V2 = c(1,2,1,2,1,5,4), V3 =    c('date1','date1','date2','date3','date4','date1','date2'))

dat
V1 V2    V3
1  1 date1
2  1 date1
1  2 date2
1  2 date3
2  1 date4
5  4 date1
4  5 date2
```

I want to find unique pairs from column 1 and 2 (so that row 2, 3, 4, 5 are all consolidated into a single unique pair) regardless of order (1, 2 = 2, 1). I found this nice code on SO ([Unique pairs in R, ignoring order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28284656/unique-pairs-in-r-ignoring-order]))

```
colwise <- function(dat) data.frame(unique(cbind(pmin(dat[,1], dat[,2]), pmax(dat[,1], dat[,2]))))
```

Which works great for pulling out columns 1 and 2.

```
colwise(dat)
V1 V2
1  1
1  2
4  5
```

However, I would like to find the unique pairs (as above) but also include the entire first row from the original dataset for each unique pair. In the example above the final output would be

```
dat
V1 V2    V3
1  1 date1
1  2 date1
4  5 date1
```

In my actual dataset I have many more columns and several ~1 million rows, though only 100-200 truly unique combinations of column 1 and 2. Additionally, the unique pair columns are not actually columns 1, 2 in my dataset so the ability to specify specific columns to test for uniqueness is important.

Does anyone have some good thoughts for how to modify the colwise function or how to use the resulting set of unique pairs to pull from the original dataframe the first entire row based on that unique pair?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `duplicated` instead of `unique` to get the duplicated indices for the unique pairs instead of the unique pairs, then remove the duplicates:

```
dat <- data.frame(V1 = c(1,1,2,1,2,4,5), V2 = c(1,2,1,2,1,5,4), V3 = c('date1','date1','date2','date3','date4','date1','date2'))

dup <- function(dat) duplicated(cbind(pmin(dat[,1], dat[,2]), pmax(dat[,1], dat[,2])))

print(dat[!dup(dat),])
##  V1 V2    V3
##1  1  1 date1
##2  1  2 date1
##6  4  5 date1
```

Note, this only gives you the entire row for the first of these duplicated unique pairs, and you said that is what you want.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Works great for what I needed! I'd been looking at how to incorporate duplicated, but didn't realize it was going to be that simple.

Answer (score 4):

The `distinct` function in the [dplyr](https://github.com/hadley/dplyr) package does this. To ignore order, you can define the `smaller` and `larger` columns first, and remove those columns afterwards:

```
library(dplyr)
dat %>%
  distinct(smaller = pmin(V1, V2),
           larger = pmax(V1, V2),
           .keep_all = TRUE) %>%
  select(-smaller, -larger)
```

The `.keep_all` argument (since dplyr 0.5) tells it not to discard the other (non-V1/V2) columns.

Comment: This is a great implementation and is very fast. Much faster than what I had been using previously. I accepted the answer of @aichao because it showed how to modify my code to solve my problem, but this implementation is better than what I had. Thank you, always great to see new applications of dplyr

Answer (score 0):

You could first sort the columns and then use `duplicated`:

```
dat <- transform(dat, V1a=pmin(V1,V2), V2a=pmax(V1,V2))
idx <- which(!duplicated(dat[,c("V1a", "V2a")]))
dat <- dat[idx,]
```