# Find unique pairs of words ignoring their order in two columns in R

Tags: r, unique

I have a data frame that contains duplicated values in two columns.

```
   dat<-data.frame(V1 = c("home","cat","fire","sofa","kitchen","sofa"), 
                    V2 = c("cat","home","water","TV","knife","TV"), V3 = c('date1','date1','date2','date3','date4','date3'))

       V1    V2    V3
1    home   cat date1
2     cat  home date1
3    fire water date2
4    sofa    TV date3
5 kitchen knife date4
6    sofa    TV date1
```

I would like to obtain from this dataframe unique pairs ignoring the order in which the pair is presented between the two columns.

This would be the result that I would like to obtain:

```
       V1    V2    V3
1    home   cat date1
2    fire water date2
3    sofa    TV date3
4 kitchen knife date4
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unique pairs in R, ignoring order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28284656/unique-pairs-in-r-ignoring-order)

Comment: I tried and it does not work. Did you try?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`dat[!duplicated(t(apply(dat, 1, sort))),]`

Using `apply` and `sort` will loop through each row and sort. We can then transpose the output and determine duplicates using `duplicated`. Because `duplicated` returns a boolean we then subset all rows in `dat` where `duplicated = FALSE`.

Comment: This indeed worked. But what about If I want now join in the result table, other values obtained from the same pairs but save in another dataframe. Also in this case I would need to ignore order of the columns.

Comment: Could you provide an example?

Comment: I thought it was more appropriate to ask another question for this issue.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54448429/find-matches-between-unique-pairs-of-two-dataframes-and-bind-values-in-r/54448696#54448696

Answer (score 0):

```
library(igraph)
myList = lapply(split(dat, dat$V3), function(x) {  # Split the data by third column
    g1 = graph.data.frame(x, directed = FALSE)  # create undirected graph
    g2 = simplify(g1, remove.multiple = TRUE)  # remove duplicates (same pairs)
    get.edgelist(g2)   #Convert to list of pairs
})

# Add the date back and then combine rows
do.call(rbind, lapply(names(myList), function(nm) data.frame(myList[[nm]], nm)))
#       X1    X2    nm
#1    home   cat date1
#2    fire water date2
#3    sofa    TV date3
#4 kitchen knife date4
```